# How can I handle excessive pressure in a water heat circuit?

Tags: radiant-heating

I am playing with radiant heating in my garage.  I want to put copper coil wrapped around the flue pipe, 5 feet out a SharkBite connector from copper to pex and the same for the cold water intake back to the coil on the stove.

Water expands when this gets hot, so I need a relief or discharge but can't find online what I should do for this.  Is there a like a pressure valve I could get at like home depot that discharges the hot water if there is too much pressure?

This is really just learning and playing around in an open garage.  I don't need to follow all the standards I just want to see how efficient it is...

any ideas would be appriciated.

thanks

Comment: Seems like a small [expansion tank](https://www.amazon.com/expansion-tank/s?k=expansion+tank) would do, but I'm not a heating system designer.

Comment: Are you running this pipe under the slab or something? Otherwise, pushing air over your stove is much easier.

Comment: I would use acr rated soft copper it is rated to 800 psi in most cases and working pressures of 400 psi. This is what we use for the high and low pressure sides of heat pumps. And as Isherwood mentioned a small pressure tank would be a good idea but a totally closed system should have a TPR relief valve similar to a water heater it is surprising how quickly a low pressure system can turn into a high pressure and blow, steam expands ~1800 times its contained volume and causes nasty burns.

Comment: Yet you haven't updated the post. O_o

Comment: I'm rather concerned by your comment " I don't need to follow all the standards".  Standards are there for a reason (usually safety).

Comment: @Milwrdfan don't be.  It means I'm not spending all the money to have this perfectly setup and respecting all the guidelines.  I'm just playing with it in and open area, so if it leaks its not a big deal.  unless it explodes.  lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an expansion tank on a closed-circuit hydronic loop. You'll also need air vents for removing the dissolved air when it comes out of solution as the water (or antifreeze) heats. These are commonly deployed on the bottom and top of an "air scoop" which is a standard hydronic heating component.

You ALSO need a pressure and temperature relief valve, but you don't want that venting on a regular basis - the expansion tank should deal with normal variation. The relief valve is for when things go wrong.